# Remove all elements from array that do not start with a certain string

Tags: php, arrays, key, filtering, array-filter

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(
  'abc' => 0,
  'foo-bcd' => 1,
  'foo-def' => 1,
  'foo-xyz' => 0,
  // ...
)
```

How can I retain only the elements that start with `foo-`?

Comment: Having an array with prefixes like this is a code smell. Extract those values into an object holding these values or at least make the prefix point to an array and add the values to it.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766898/php-get-array-values-of-a-string-array-that-match-substrings-of-another-string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modification to **erisco**'s Functional approach,

```
array_filter($signatureData[0]["foo-"], function($k) {
    return strpos($k, 'foo-abc') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Any difference in performance or usefulness compared to array_filter_key version provided by @erisco?

Comment: Nope. There should not any difference in performance I guess. @MaciekSemik

Comment: This is a core PHP function so it should be preferred.

Answer (score 153):

Functional approach:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'foo-') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Procedural approach:

```
$only_foo = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'foo-') === 0) {
        $only_foo[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Procedural approach using objects:

```
$i = new ArrayIterator($array);
$only_foo = array();
while ($i->valid()) {
    if (strpos($i->key(), 'foo-') === 0) {
        $only_foo[$i->key()] = $i->current();
    }
    $i->next();
}
```

Comment: Note PHP 5.6 adds the ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY flag to `array_filter()`, which you can use instead of supplying a custom `array_filter_key()` function.

Comment: Can you please just add the array_filter_key function to your example? I kept getting an error and had to re-read your post multiple times before recognizing my mistake. It's not hard to just post the code, save a click, and save somebody time troubleshooting. Thanks.

Comment: This answer will be fooling a lot of researchers and wasting their time until they realize that `array_filter_key()` is not a native function.  Researchers shouldn't have to link-chase to receive the whole solution.

Comment: With php8 you can also use `str_starts_with($key, 'foo-')`

Answer (score 38):

This is how I would do it, though I can't give you a more efficient advice before understanding what you want to do with the values you get.

```
$search = "foo-";
$search_length = strlen($search);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, $search_length) == $search) {
        ...use the $value...
    }
}
```

Comment: You also can use: `foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (0 === strpos($key, 'foo-')) {
        ...use the $value...
    }
}`

Comment: The "4" here needs to be adjusted to whatever length "foo-" is.

Answer (score 26):

Simply I used `array_filter` function to achieve the solution as like follows

```
<?php

$input = array(
    'abc' => 0,
    'foo-bcd' => 1,
    'foo-def' => 1,
    'foo-xyz' => 0,
);

$filtered = array_filter($input, function ($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'foo-') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

print_r($filtered);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [foo-bcd] => 1
    [foo-def] => 1
    [foo-xyz] => 0
)
```

For live check https://3v4l.org/lJCse

Comment: Pay attention that this needs at least PHP 5.6.0 (due to the use of the constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY).

In prior versions you can use:
[code]

Answer (score 20):

From PHP 5.3 you can use the `preg_filter` function: [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php)

```
$unprefixed_keys = preg_filter('/^foo-(.*)/', '$1', array_keys( $arr ));

// Result:
// $unprefixed_keys === array('bcd','def','xyz')
```

Answer (score 19):

```
$arr_main_array = array('foo-test' => 123, 'other-test' => 456, 'foo-result' => 789);

foreach($arr_main_array as $key => $value){
    $exp_key = explode('-', $key);
    if($exp_key[0] == 'foo'){
         $arr_result[] = $value;
    }
}

if(isset($arr_result)){
    print_r($arr_result);
}
```

Comment: Before you take this solution, the one below is better. Never use array functions where simple string function will suffice. String functions are WAY faster. This will 'lag' with large arrays.

Comment: I don't see the point of exploding the array keys into arrays. They are strings and the original question is just asking about a string prefix. Also OP is asking for "the elements" rather than just the values, so the numerically-indexed result is going to be useless - the keys are clearly important here, with the values being (presumably) anonymous 1/0 flags.

Answer (score 14):

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
   if(preg_match('/^foo-/', $key))
   {
        // You can access $value or create a new array based off these values
   }
}
```

Comment: A regex is not really necessary in this case. The substr method is slightly more efficient

Comment: @jfoucher: That's true, however, personally, it's easier to read.

Comment: It may be more flexible, but comes at the cost of needing to escape special preg characters if you *don't* want to do a regular expression match. So use with caution. I would suggest you use REs only if you need REs.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Suresh Velusamy's answer above (which needs at least PHP 5.6.0) you can use the following if you are on a prior version of PHP:

```
<?php

$input = array(
    'abc' => 0,
    'foo-bcd' => 1,
    'foo-def' => 1,
    'foo-xyz' => 0,
);

$filtered = array_filter(array_keys($input), function($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'foo-') === 0;
});

print_r($filtered);

/* Output:
Array
(
    [1] => foo-bcd
    [2] => foo-def
    [3] => foo-xyz
)
// the numerical array keys are the position in the original array!
*/

// if you want your array newly numbered just add:
$filtered = array_values($filtered);

print_r($filtered);

/* Output:
Array
(
    [0] => foo-bcd
    [1] => foo-def
    [2] => foo-xyz
)
*/
```

Comment: Please note (or at least for me) that this only returns the array key's that match. The answer below by @suresh-velusamy extracts the actual array with the original `$key => $value` pair. It is stated in the output of this answer, but was not yet mentioned explicitly

Answer (score 2):

From PHP5.6, the array keys can be the sole subject of the filtration by using the [ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.constants.php#:%7E:text=ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY%20(int)) constant/flag.

From PHP7.4, [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) make custom functions more concise and allow values to be passed into the custom function's scope without `use()`.

From PHP8, [str_starts_with()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) can take the place of `strpos(...) === 0`

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Nog5U))

```
$array = [
  'abc' => 0,
  'foo-bcd' => 1,
  'foo-def' => 1,
  'foo-xyz' => 0,
];

$prefix = 'foo';

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($key) => str_starts_with($key, $prefix),
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'foo-bcd' => 1,
  'foo-def' => 1,
  'foo-xyz' => 0,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might pass a key-value single dimensional array and a specific prefix string 'foo-' to the function just made: filter_array_key_with_prefix

```php
<?php

function filter_array_key_with_prefix($arr, $prefix) {
  return array_filter($arr, function($k) use ($prefix) {
    return strpos($k, $prefix) === 0;
  }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}

$arr = array(
  'abc' => 0,
  'foo-bcd' => 1,
  'foo-def' => 1,
  'foo-xyz' => 0,
  // ...
);

$filtered = filter_array_key_with_prefix($arr, 'foo-');

var_dump($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["foo-bcd"]=>
  int(1)
  ["foo-def"]=>
  int(1)
  ["foo-xyz"]=>
  int(0)
}
```