# Check if string starts with

Tags: php, string

In PHP I have a list of country telephone codes. e.g: US 1, Egypt 20 ....
I need to check if a given string starts with `00[ANY NUMBER FROM THE LIST]`.
How can I achieve this and return the country code?

Comment: You could do this with regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions

Comment: Or - if the numbers are strings - with `substr`: [substring info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Maybe the answer that was listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979238/php-get-all-keys-from-a-array-that-start-with-a-certain-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$codes = array(1 => 'US', 20 => 'Egypt');
$phone = '002087458454';

foreach ($codes as $code => $country) {
  if (strpos($phone, "00$code") === 0)
    break;
}

echo $code;    // 20
echo $country; // Egypt
```

Comment: You must check for `=== 0` instead of `== 0`. `strpos()` can return `FALSE` (string not found) and `FALSE == 0` is true!!!

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [PHP - get all keys from a array that start with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979238/php-get-all-keys-from-a-array-that-start-with-a-certain-string)

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, 2) == "00") {
        echo "$key\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
$str ="0041";

if(preg_match('#00[0-9]+#', $str, $array)){
    echo substr($array[0], 2);
}
```

Comment: It will echo the whole string.

Comment: It will echo the first two chars now: `00`.

Comment: Please note regex may have a performance impact in large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
$country_code = substr($string, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [explode function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) to separate the string in arrays, and you can acess with `$string`.