# How to search array form his key for getting value in result

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I am working on creating a search box for my website which search my website pages. for this i create an array of containing a page name as key and it's link as a value. like below

```
   <?php
        $linkArray = array(
            'Add New Vendor' => base_url().'index.php/vvendor',
            'Add New Plan' => base_url().'index.php/plan',
            'venodr page' => base_url().'index.php/vendor',
            'Employee' => base_url().'index.php/employee'
    );
    ?>
```

and a search box like

```
<input type="text" name="search_box" />
```

how to do it in the codeigniter way...???

Comment: `array_column($linkArray, 'column_name')`.

Comment: Check this [ex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979238/php-get-all-keys-from-a-array-that-start-with-a-certain-string)

Comment: `site_url('vvendor')`, etc. would be preferable.

Comment: do you want to search from array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Write in your controller function:**

```
$search_box=$_POST['search_box'];    
 $linkArray = array(
            'Add New Vendor' => base_url().'index.php/vvendor',
            'Add New Plan' => base_url().'index.php/plan',
            'venodr page' => base_url.'index.php/vendor',
            'Employee' => base_url.'index.php/employee'
    );
    if (array_key_exists($search_box, $linkArray )) {
        echo "FOUND: ".$search_box;
    }
```

[--Reference--](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: For smarter search, you can do for example `$linkArray = array('add new vendor'...); if (array_key_exists(mb_strtolower($search_box), $linkArray))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchParam = 'Add New Plan'; 
$linkArray = array(
            'Add New Vendor' => base_url().'index.php/vvendor',
            'Add New Plan' => base_url().'index.php/plan',
            'venodr page' => base_url.'index.php/vendor',
            'Employee' => base_url.'index.php/employee'
);
foreach($linkArray as $key => $value)
{
    $pattern = $key;
    $subject = $searchParam;
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
    if($matches)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also use other string function to match string

Comment: i put this code in the controller and getting to much errors sir??