# Show all variables post php if name has exist one word

Tags: php, forms, post

I want show all post variables if name of variables has start add-

for example: this is a full string with post variables:

```
Array ( [PartNumber] => sfd [Description] => dsf [Issue] => dfs [Customer] => J.C.B. SERVICE [widget7-table_length] => 5 [add_332/F2684] => [add_333/D1641] => sdf [add_333/D1202] => [add_332/F3144] => sdf [add_332/F3147] => sfd [makeassy] => )
```

I want to display in array only

```
[add_332/F2684] => [add_333/D1641] => sdf [add_333/D1202] => [add_332/F3144] => sdf [add_332/F3147] => sfd
```

I'm trying

```
print_r($_POST['add_%']);
```

But, how you see this post, it's not working. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - get all keys from a array that start with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979238/php-get-all-keys-from-a-array-that-start-with-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_filter` to extract specific array keys:

```
$output = array_filter($_POST, function($e) {
    return strpos($e, 'add_') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You coudl try using  `preg_grep()`

```
$res= preg_grep ('/^add_ (\w+)/i', $_POST);

var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution with Foreach

```
<?php
    $x = array(
         'PartNumber' => 'sfd',
         'Description' => 'dsf',
         'add_332/F2684' =>'asd', 
         'add_333/D1641' =>'sdf' ,
         'add_333/D1202' => 'asd',
         'TESTEST' => 'ASDASD' );

    $tmp = array();
    foreach($x as $key => $value)
    {
        if(substr( $key, 0, 3 ) === "add")
        {
            array_push($tmp,array($key =>$value));
        }
    }
    die(print_r($tmp));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [add_332/F2684] => asd
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [add_333/D1641] => sdf
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [add_333/D1202] => asd
    )

)
1
```