# $this keyword and compact function

Tags: php, arrays, oop

In some contexts, we can use an `array($this, 'variable')` syntax, to refer to object properties. Why doesn't `compact(array($this, 'variable'))` work? Is there a way to work around this?

```php
class someclass {

    $result = 'something';

    public function output() {
        compact($this->result); // $this is a OOP keyword and I don't know how to use it inside a compact() brackets
    }
}
```

I have found only one solution at the moment:

```php
$result = $this->result;
compact('result');
```

But this is ugly.

Comment: I don't know a lot about this function, or "extract", but I can tell you you're missing a parentheses at the end there.  Possibly just a transposing issue, but maybe that's your problem?

In other news, I would venture to guess that $this is not part of the object's symbol table, and thus doesn't pack properly.

Comment: there is no need for `array()`, and you must specify 'this', not $this.

Comment: @greg0rie, is that works by you? Which PHP version do you use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: don't use `compact()`.  In this situation, it's pointless (in most situations it's pointless, but that's another story).  Instead, what's wrong with just returning an array?

```
return array('variable' => $this->variable);
```

Comment: "in most situations it's pointless" - would you please elaborate?

Comment: i dont get your note too. Compact help me a lot of times

Comment: Although I agree in this scenario, as @chris asks, can you explain why the function is pointless so others can understand please?

Comment: i think he just meant to say you dont need a function to do array('key' => $val).. lol

Comment: Personally I don't like to use compact. At a glance PHPStorm doesn't highlight a problem when I use variable names that haven't been defined. Also refactoring variable names is a little more difficult (Have to use rename all occurrences, which I don't love doing)

Answer (score 16):

I know this is old, but I wanted something like this for a project I'm working on. Thought I'd share the solution I came up with:

```
extract(get_object_vars($this));
return compact('result');
```

It scales rather nicely. For example:

```
<?php

class Thing {
    private $x, $y, $z;

    public function __construct($x, $y, $z) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
        $this->z = $z;
    }

    public function getXYZ() {
        extract(get_object_vars($this));
        return compact('x', 'y', 'z');
    }
}


$thing = new Thing(1, 2, 3);
print_r($thing->getXYZ());
```

Use with care.

Comment: `$vars = get_object_vars($this); extract($vars); return compact(array_keys($vars));` to get all the properties of an object

Answer (score 9):

`compact()` looks for the variable name in the [**current symbol table**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php). `$this` does not exist in there. What do you expect the name of `$this` to be anyway?

You can do:

```
class Foo
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $that = $this;
        $var = '2';
        print_r( compact(array('that', 'var')) );
    }
}
```

Ironically, once you assigned $this to $that, $this can also be compacted with 'this' nistead of 'that'. See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52110. For performance reasons `$this` and super-globals are only populated when they are needed. If the aren't needed they don't exist.

---

**EDIT after Update**

Your `compact($this->result);` looks for 'something' defined within the **local/current** scope of the `output()` method. Since there is no such variable, the resulting array will be empty. This would work:

```
public function output() 
{
    $something = 1;
    print_r( compact($this->result) );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to use `get_class_vars()`, which returns an associative array of all properties (class vars) of the provided class, with the var name as the key. Use `get_class_vars( get_called_class() )` from within the class to get that class' name as a string. `get_class( $this )` works as well.

Of course, this gives you **all** the properties of the class (regardless of access control modifier), so chances are you want to also filter this list. An easy (if somewhat obfuscated) way to do this is to use `array_intersect_key()` along with `array_flip()` as per [this SE Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260168/467386). So the whole thing looks like:

```
array_intersect_key( get_class_vars( get_called_class() ), array_flip( array( 'var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3' ) ) );
```

You'll have to decide if the resulting code is really worth it. It's probably easier to read `array( 'var_1' => $this->var_1, 'var_2' => $this->var_2 );` as [@ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995062/467386) points out.

However, because a) I like [Yak Shaving](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving) and b) because I am a very industrious [lazy programmer](http://threevirtues.com/) and c) there was probably a one-liner in Perl that did this elegantly, here's the code in the context of the problem I was trying to address: overriding an associative array (that's also a property of the current class) with a number (but not all) of other properties of the same class.

```
<?php
class Test {
    protected $var_1 = 'foo';
    private $var_2 = 'bar';
    public $var_3 = 'baz';
    private $ignored_var = 'meh';

    public $ary = array( 
        'var_1' => 'bletch',
        'var_2' => 'belch',
        'var_4' => 'gumbo',
        'var_5' => 'thumbo'
    );

    public function test(){
        $override = array_intersect_key( get_class_vars( get_called_class() ), array_flip( array( 'var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3' ) ) );
        return array_merge( $this->ary, $override );
    }
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump( $test->test() );
```

Which produces the expected output:

```
array(5) { ["var_1"]=> string(3) "foo" ["var_2"]=> string(3) "bar" ["var_4"]=> string(5) "gumbo" ["var_5"]=> string(6) "thumbo" ["var_3"]=> string(3) "baz" }
```

Note that in my own usage, I wouldn't have broken this out into 2 lines, but I wanted to keep the code that refers to the OP separate.

Comment: *grunt grunt grunt* - [the sound a yak makes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZ_zm5oOuLc)

Comment: As a humorous anecdote, after shaving this particular Yak and writing this lovely SE Answer, it turns out that it won't work for me at all: my class properties are not named the same as the expected parameters in my associative array. Looks like I'll be using 'var_1' => $this->some_other_var. DOH

Answer (score 2):

I needed something like this today – the functionality of `compact` but in the scope of an object/array instead of the current symbol table. So I wrote this:

```php
/**
 * Returns an associative array of object properties or array elements with values
 *
 * @see https://www.php.net/compact
 * @param mixed $obj The object from which to take properties
 * @param mixed $args The property names as strings or arrays of strings
 * @return array<string,mixed>
 */
function compact_with(mixed $obj, ...$args): array
{
    $ret = [];
    array_map(
        function ($v) use ($obj, &$ret) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $ret += compact_with($obj, ...$v);
            } else {
                $ret[$v] = is_array($obj) ? $obj[$v] : $obj->$v;
            }
        },
        $args
    );

    return $ret ?? [];
}
```

As with `compact`, it can accept strings or arrays as arguments, and works recursively with the latter, giving precedence to the first instance of a string label. And like `compact` since PHP 7.3, it emits a notice if an invalid property name is included as an argument.

Example:

```php
$ob = new class {
    public $foo = 123;
    public $bar = 456;
    public $baz = 789;
};
print_r(compact_with($ob, "baz", "foo"));

$arr = [
    "foo" => 123,
    "bar" => 456,
    "baz" => 789
];
print_r(compact_with($arr, "baz", "foo"));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [baz] => 789
    [foo] => 123
)
Array
(
    [baz] => 789
    [foo] => 123
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You must define index-fields. Something like:
$array = compact('this', 'variable')

http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for the same exact thing, wanting to preventing the *ugliness*. Later I ended up using the follow code, thought I should contribute it here:

```
return array_merge(compact('other', 'beautiful', 'variables'), 
  ['result' => $this->result]);
```

This way you can continue using compact for your other beautiful variables!