# How to filter an associative arrays using array of keys in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have an associative arrays and an array of keys.

```
$A = array('a'=>'book', 'b'=>'pencil', 'c'=>'pen');
$B = array('a', 'b');
```

How I build an associative array from all element of `$A` where the key is in `$B`?
For the example above, the answer should be

```
$C = array('a'=>'book', 'b'=>'pencil');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$keys = array_keys($B);
$C = array();
foreach ($A as $key => $value)
{
  if (in_array($key, $keys))
  {
    $C[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
$keys = array_flip($B);
$C = array_intersect_key($A,$keys);
```

Answer (score 4):

`array_intersect_key($A,array_combine($B,$B))`

or better: `array_intersect_key($my_array, array_flip($allowed))`

from the question: [PHP: How to use array_filter() to filter array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution which checks that the key exists in `$A` before appending it to `$C`

```
$A = array('a'=>'book', 'b'=>'pencil', 'c'=>'pen');
$B = array('a', 'b');

$C = array();
foreach ($B as $bval) {
  // If the $B key exists in $A, add it to $C
  if (isset($A[$bval])) $C[$bval] = $A[$bval];
}

var_dump($C);

// Prints:
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(4) "book"
  ["b"]=>
  string(6) "pencil"
}
```

Comment: Obviously wrong :/. OP need to filter an array with another, your solution doesn't. And the result in `$C` should be an associative array, in your solution it's an indexed one.

Comment: Edited to make  `$C` associative

Comment: Edit: And I didn't mean to be ironic, you solution **is working** and is - I personnaly found - more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

To my immense surprise, the foreach loop method is faster.

The following quick benchmark script gives me results:
`array_intersect_key: 0.76424908638
foreach loop: 0.6393928527832`

```
$A = array('a'=>'book', 'b'=>'pencil', 'c'=>'pen');
$B = array('a', 'b');

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
$c = array_intersect_key($A,array_flip($B));
}

$t1 = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
$C = array();
    foreach ($B as $bval) {
          // If the $B key exists in $A, add it to $C
          if (isset($A[$bval])) $C[$bval] = $A[$bval];
    }
}

$t2 = microtime(true);
echo "array_intersect_key: " . ($t1 - $start), "\n";
echo "foreach loop: " . ($t2 - $t1), "\n";
```

Comment: Awesome \o/ (and some more characters to reach 15).