# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens PDO insert

Tags: php, pdo, insert

```
function mysql_insert($data_array){
    $sql = "insert into `". $this->table_name. '`';

    $array_keys = array_keys($data_array);
    $array_keys_comma = implode(",\n", preg_replace('/^(.*?)$/', "`$1`", $array_keys));

    for($a=0,$b=count($data_array); $a<$b; $a++){ $question_marks .="?,";  }

    $array_values = array_values($data_array);
    $array_values_comma = implode(",", $array_values);

    $sql.= " ($array_keys_comma) ";
    $sql.= " values(". substr($question_marks, 0,-1) .")";

    $prepare = $this->connDB->prepare($sql);
    $insert = $prepare->execute(array($array_values_comma));

}
```

I want to creat like this universal functions, $data_array-comes from $_POST
This function will work for all form. But i dont know what is my wrong :S

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDO PHP insert into DB from an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507496/pdo-php-insert-into-db-from-an-associative-array)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$array_values_comma is a scalar after you implode() the array.  So you always pass an array of one element to your execute() function.  You should pass $array_values.

Here's how I'd write this function:

```
function mysql_insert($data_array){
    $columns = array_keys($data_array);
    $column_list_delimited = implode(",", 
      array_map(function ($name) { return "`$name`"; }, $columns));

    $question_marks = implode(",", array_fill(1, count($data_array), "?"));

    $sql = "insert into `{$this->table_name}` ($column_list_delimited) 
      values ($question_marks)";

    // always check for these functions returning FALSE, which indicates an error
    // or alternatively set the PDO attribute to use exceptions

    $prepare = $this->connDB->prepare($sql);
    if ($prepare === false) {
      trigger_error(print_r($this->connDB->errorInfo(),true), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $insert = $prepare->execute(array_values($data_array));    
    if ($insert === false) {
      trigger_error(print_r($prepare->errorInfo(),true), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

A further improvement would be to do some validation of `$this->table_name` and the keys of `$data_array` so you know they match an existing table and its columns.

See [my answer to escaping column name with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448274/escaping-column-name-with-pdo/13448443#13448443) for an example of validating column names.

Comment: this function is vulnerable to SQL injection through identifiers.  You don't need to check PDO functions but make them throw exceptions

Comment: @YourCommonSense, that's why I recommended to validate table names and column names.  I did mention the option of using exceptions, but not all PHP developers are comfortable using exceptions.  Downvoting this answer is unwarranted.

Comment: That's why my other answer uses *whitelisting* approach (note the obligatory `$fields` parameter) and thus invulnerable