# INSERT into Table On Columns That Exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose I have a very large array of information for a user:

```
$user=array(
"name"=>"john",
"ip"=>"xx.xx.xx.xx",
"email"=>"john@something.com",
//lots more values
)
```

Let's also suppose that this information needs to **go into more than one table**. For instance a `username` needs to go table `users`, `address` needs to go into a `details` table, etc.

Now, I use a certain self-made function to insert into my tables that matches **array keys to column names** and **array values to the values being inputted**. Something similar to this:

```
function insert_sql($table, arr $values){
    GLOBAL $dbc;
    $sql="INSERT INTO `$table` (".implode(array_keys($values), ", ").") VALUES (".implode(array_values($values), ", ").")";
    $dbc->prepare($sql)->execute();
    return $dbc->lastInsertId();

}
//I don't actually use this function, just trying to show you what is being accomplished.
```

The problem is that my function uses **all the keys** and **all the values**, so when I just need certain parts of the array put into multiple tables, it doesn't work.

The question is:

**How do I make an INSERT statement ignore a column if it doesn't exist?**  So if I insert `name`,`email`,`address`, into table `users`, but this table doesn't have an address column, I need it to insert the row with the name and email but simply ignore the fact that the address column is not there.

EDIT: The other option is to make an array with the columns of a table and use it to filter the values array. Although I am not really sure how to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find given table column names:

```
SELECT 
column_name
FROM 
information_schema.columns
WHERE 
table_name =  'tablename'
```

And then just whitelist your keys in `$values` array

Example:

```
function insert_sql($table, array $values){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name =  :tablename";
        /* @var $stmt PDOStatement */
        $stmt  = $connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(
            'tablename' => $table
        ));
        $columns = array_flip($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0));
        $values  = array_intersect_key($values, $columns);
        var_dump($values);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have the columns as values of array $columns. What's the best way to filter the $values based on the $columns (remember the keys of array $values are the columns).

Comment: Nevermind, I found this answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys

Comment: @hellohellosharp I've provided an example, using `array_intersect_key` but array_filter is also fine

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make an INSERT statement ignore a column if it doesn't exist?
>   So if I insert name,email,address, into table users, but this table
>   doesn't have an address column, I need it to insert the row with the
>   name and email but simply ignore the fact that the address column is
>   not there.

You can't

Instead you should map your data to the appropriate tables with separate inserts.

Comment: Sure, separate INSERTS can be used, I guess I am just looking for a way to dynamically split the array then to have the right values.