# INSERT INTO Statement All Columns that exist in destination table

Tags: mysql, insert

Say I have a table (lets call it DB10) which has 10 columns. I have another table with 15 columns (DB15), 10 of which are identical to the columns in DB10 in terms of name and data type.

I want to insert all the columns in DB10 into DB15. I have tried using the following:

**INSERT INTO DB15
SELECT *
FROM DB10**

But this gives me Error Code 1136 "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". From what I understand through research is that its trying to map 10 values to 15 columns.

So my question is, how is this possible without having to enter the individual columns. Can I perhaps use a function to make it assume a value of null for columns that can't be mapped?

The reason I want to do this? I have more than 10 columns to be mapped, and I just want to simplify the SQL script, smaller scripts are easier to check.

I've done my research and found this question here: [INSERT into Table On Columns That Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248966/insert-into-table-on-columns-that-exist)

It seems like the guy wants essentially the same thing done, but he 's trying to perform it on multiple linked tables and arrays, I couldn't follow how I could apply it to my case.

Comment: "I have a database which has 10 columns". A database can contain *tables*, which can contain columns.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. You have to enter all the column names.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact it's best practice tot list columns in INSERT and SELECT statements.

However it's possible to generate the list programmaticly:

```
<?php
$fields = array();
$cResult = $sDb->query("SHOW COLUMNS IN DB10");
while ($columns = $cResult->fetch_row()) {
    $fields[] = $columns[0];
}
$sDb->query("INSERT INTO DB15 (" . implode(',', $fields) . ") SELECT " . 
           implode(',', $fields) . " FROM DB10"); 
}
```

Assuming remaining columns in DB15 are either nullable or have a default assigned

Comment: I don think that t is best practice it is the only syntactically correct way of doing it.

Comment: Whats with the weird syntax? Is this sql language? I'm using MySQL Workbench and I get red crosses next to almost all the rows.

Comment: It's php syntax, not sql.

Comment: Okay so it can't be done on MySQL Workbench? What do I need, I'd prefer to get it done on the existing software if possible. I did specify MySQL in the title but for some reason a mod edited it out..

Comment: Yes it can be done in workbench, but then you need to enter the individual columns in the query