# postgresql INSERT INTO all columns from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, drop-duplicates

I am trying to write a method that removes duplicates from tables, without having to know the details of the table for generality (i.e., it should run on any table).

I am using the following method from [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/) (last method) through `psycopg2`:

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable (LIKE "{table}");
INSERT INTO tempTable(*)
  SELECT
    DISTINCT ON ("{column}") *
    FROM "{table}";
DROP TABLE "{table}";
ALTER TABLE tempTable
  RENAME TO "{table}";
DROP table tempTable
```

The problem is that you can't use * to get all columns inside the `INSERT INTO` command.  We are expected to specify a list of all the columns to insert, which is probably good for control, but is bad for my purpose here.

I know I can get the list of column names for the table with

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = "{table}"
```

but I can't just plug that as a subquery in place of the `*`.

Answers to this [8 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842581/insert-into-statement-all-columns-that-exist-in-destination-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) state that it's just not possible in SQL.  That might still be true, or it might not be true.

Can this be done now?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the duplicates? You can use VACUUM FULL or CLUSTER afterwards to shrink the table, if needed.

Comment: Yes, I ran this by creating a temporary uniqueID column, remove duplicates with that as an index, then removing that column.  It was plenty fast but less elegant.  If there is a an easier way with these commands you mention, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Valid point @FrankHeikens, the CTAS approach is meaninfull only with a large number of duplicates or if also a table reorganisation is required. For in-place delete see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6583916/4808122)

Answer (score 2):

Your link points to `MySQL`database, in `PostgreSQL` is perfectly valid to use `insert` *without the column list*.

```
INSERT INTO tempTable 
  SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (a) *
    FROM t;
```

It is **not the best practice** (as this may cause problems if the column order is sudenly not as expected), but for your use case where the target table is created with `like` from the source table will work.

Two additional points

- You may want to add `order by` in the select distinct to enable a *deterministic* outcome (which duplicated row(s) will be removed and which preserve).
- the final `DROP table tempTable` is misplaced as this table *does not exists* anymore as beeing *renamed* in the previous statement...