# Get subset of array by specifying keys

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a built-in function for:

```
print_r(array_***([
    'foo' => 1,
    'bar' => 2,
    'baz' => 3,
    'qux' => 4,
], ['foo', 'qux']));
```

to produce:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 1
    [qux] => 4
)
```

?

Comment: @FelixKling I've tried functions from that answer. They both return empty arrays.

Comment: You also need `array_flip`: http://codepad.org/yXIB1ECZ

Comment: Better duplicate: [PHP: How to use array_filter() to filter array keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4260086/218196).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the array_intersect_key function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

Running:

```
var_dump(array_intersect_key(array('foo'=>1,'bar'=>2,'baz'=>3,'qux'=>4),array('foo'=>true,'qux'=>true)));
```

Should give you:

```
array(2) { ["foo"]=> int(1) ["qux"]=> int(4) }
```