# php count only integer keys of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Exist some simple function for count only the integer keys of an array?

for example i have this array:

```
0 => "string"
1 => "string"
"#aaa" => "string"
```

I need count only the first two element without using a custom foreach loop.

Comment: By 'count' do you mean add/sum or include only integer-based keys?

Comment: with count i mean a numeric count of the only integer-based keys, so for this example the result is 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to use array\_filter() to filter array keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the integer keys, try

```
count(array_filter(array_keys($array), function($key) {
    return is_int($key);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a check on each key to loop through only the numbered keys:

```
foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    if( is_numeric($key) ) { //Only numbered keys will pass
        //Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, OP only wants to match integer keys. `is_numeric` will match decimal numbers too

Comment: Sure, I guess it all depends on OP's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```
$int_keys = count(array_filter(array_keys($arr), 'is_int'));
```