# Intersect and Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, filtering

Similar to the question: [Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array) only I want to drop any keys that arent in common.

Essentially I tried filtering the variables by the keys via [`array_intersect_key($VARIABLES, array_flip($signature_args));`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260168/516813) and then tried to sort it with [`array_merge(array_flip($signature_args), $filtered)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098675/516813)

Shown here:

```
$VARIABLES = array('3'=>'4', '4'=>'5', '1'=>'2');
$signature_args = array('1', '2', '3');

$filtered = array_intersect_key($VARIABLES, array_flip($signature_args));
var_dump($filtered);

var_dump(array_merge(array_flip($signature_args), $filtered));
```

produces:

```
array(2) {
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

and not the

```
array(2) {
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

that I expected, why?

Comment: Before your var_dump do: `ksort($filtered);` does that do the trick for you?

Comment: @Rizier123 No, it doesnt fix the problem. If you mean to replace the `var_dump(array_merge(array_flip($signature_args), $filtered));` with `ksort($filtered);` that only works if `$signature_args` is sorted

Comment: Works fine for me even if `$signature_args` isn't sorted?! See: http://ideone.com/u3CGjG

Comment: @Rizier123 http://ideone.com/7i6FvH see, its in the wrong order (the result is supposed to be in the same order as the keys of `$signature_args`)

Comment: How should it be? 3 - 1 ?

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah, in your example the keys are '2', '3', '1', so the result so be in the same order: '3', '1'

Comment: So you want to keep the order of the keys?

Comment: @Rizier123 correct, that is the intended purpose of the second statement: `array_merge(array_flip($signature_args), $filtered)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $VARIABLES = array('3'=>'4', '4'=>'5', '1'=>'2');
    $signature_args = array('2', '3', '1');

    $filtered = array_intersect_key($VARIABLES, array_flip($signature_args));
    var_dump($filtered);

    $ordered = array();
    foreach ($signature_args as $key) {
        if(!empty($filtered[$key]))
        $ordered[$key] = $filtered[$key] ;
    }

    var_dump($ordered);

?>
```

Or if you want you can use this:

```
array_walk($signature_args, function($key) { 
    if(!empty($filtered[$key])) $ordered[$key] = $filtered[$key] ;
}, $ordered);
```

Comment: hmm, I just did a small fix, but if we're going to use our own loop, to create the result array, then theres no point in generating the `$filtered` variable, we can take the value directly from `$VARIABLES`. i.e. `$ordered[$key] = $VARIABLES[$key];`

Answer (score 0):

To use the "allowed" array not only to filter the input array but also to order the output, filter both arrays by each other, then replace (or merge) the input array into the allowed array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ogEN7))

```
$input = ['3' => '4', '4' => '5', '1' => '2'];
$allowed = ['1', '2', '3'];

$flipAllowed = array_flip($allowed);

var_export(
    array_replace(
        array_intersect_key($flipAllowed, $input), // filtered allowed
        array_intersect_key($input, $flipAllowed) // filtered input
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => '2',
  3 => '4',
)
```