# Exclude items from JSON string that is generated from PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I have a **PHP** function `$users->getFullUserList('json')` that returns a **JSON** string holding a Userlist of user data which is built from a PHP Array using PHP's `json_encode($this->userListArray)`

The PHP Array `$this->userListArray` looks something like this below before being converted into a `JSON` string...

```
Array
(
    [user1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_name] => jasondavis
            [first_name] => Jason
            [last_name] => Davis
            [is_admin] => 1
            [email_address] => jasonyrty@tyrtl.com
            [gravatar_id] => 31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144
        )

    [1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad
            [user_name] => Jeff
            [first_name] => Jeff
            [last_name] => Mosley
            [is_admin] => 1
            [email_address] => fgfgh@rtyrtyre.com
            [gravatar_id] => 5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e
        )
)
```

What I need help with is making my function `$users->getFullUserList('json')` to allow another parameter to be injected which will be an array of `keys` which should **NOT** be part of the final **JSON String**

For example if I want to generate my JSON string from the PHP Array  and have it exclude user `email_address` and `first_name` keys from the JSON string.

I do not want to simply remove them from the PHP Array as I will need access to them in PHP later on.  I just want the `keys` in my new passed in array to be excluded from the generated JSON  and still remain in the PHP Array.

```
$excludeKeysFromJson = array(
    'first_name',
    'email_address'
);

$users->getFullUserList('json', $excludeKeysFromJson)
```

I realize the simple solution would be to clone my `$this->userListArray` Array and then remove the matching keys from the `$excludeKeysFromJson` Array and generate the JSON string from the new cloned Array.

I am hoping to find a better performance method that doesn't require cloning my huge userlist array and keeping 2 copies of the userlist array with 1 missing a couple keys.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you show me your full code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array with keys filtered out using [`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-diff-key.php) and [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-flip.php) (to turn the *exclusion* array values into keys)

Something like this...

```
public function getFullUserList($format, array $exclude = []) {
    $filtered = array_map(function($user) use ($exclude) {
        return array_diff_key($user, array_flip($exclude));
    }, $this->userListArray);

    switch($format) {
        case 'json' :
            return json_encode($filtered);
        default :
            return $filtered;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/412864)

Comment: @JasonDavis there was some inspiration from this post ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys