# Grab array values with keys in specified range - PHP 5.5

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.5

In an array of arbitrary order and keys, as below

```
$myArray = array(
    1  => 'foo',
    4  => 'bar',
    6  => 'foobar',
    24 => 'barfoo',
    30 => 'fizz',
    35 => 'buzz',
    50 => 'fizzbuzz'
);
```

How can I get a segment of the array by a key range, for example, every item with a key between 5 and 40

Something like `array_range($myArray, 5, 40);`

Expected output: `array(6 => 'foobar', 24 => 'barfoo', 30 => 'fizz', 35 => 'buzz')`

This is similar to [How to use array_filter() to filter array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys) but in this case, I am restricted to PHP 5.5.

Comment: Are all the array values unique or do you expect duplicates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to use array\_filter() to filter array keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys)

Comment: You can array_flip() your array (which swaps the keys and values around), array_filter() the flipped array and then array_flip() the result back.  Of course that will only work 100% reliably with arrays that don't contain any duplicate values but if you can meet that requirement then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate the array, and use a condition to build a filtered array (here assuming an inclusive range):

```
<?php
$in = array(
    1  => 'foo',
    4  => 'bar',
    6  => 'foobar',
    24 => 'barfoo',
    30 => 'fizz',
    35 => 'buzz',
    50 => 'fizzbuzz'
);

$out = [];
foreach($in as $k => $v)
{
    if($k >= 5 && $k <= 40) {
        $out[$k] = $v;
    }
}
var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  6 => string 'foobar' (length=6)
  24 => string 'barfoo' (length=6)
  30 => string 'fizz' (length=4)
  35 => string 'buzz' (length=4)
```

Comment: Correct and working, but the accepted answer is much more concise.

Comment: More understandable at a glance, I'll give you that.

Comment: Changed this to correct answer, as I had to use it in order to keep within memory limits in larger arrays with much larger ranges.

Answer (score 3):

Define a range of keys in an array and then compute the intersection of keys:

```
$range  = array_flip(range(5, 40));
$result = array_intersect_key($myArray, $range);
```

One liner:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($myArray, array_flip(range(5, 40)));
```

Optionally to fill the range array (I just thought of the other one first and it's shorter):

```
$range = array_fill_keys(range(5, 40), 1);
```

If you want specific keys and not a range, just define an array of keys or values and flip:

```
$range = array_flip(array(6, 24, 50));
//or
$range = array(6=>1, 24=>1, 50=>1);
```

Comment: This is the most concise answer, but I kept getting out of memory issues with it :(

Answer (score 2):

If PHP version is under 5.6, **upgrade your version of PHP** - [5.5 is not even supported any longer](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).  If you can't upgrade PHP, then clearly [AbraCadaver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42006458/870729) is the one to use.

This requires PHP 5.6+, but was answered before the PHP version was clarified in the question, so I will leave it for reference.

Using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - so long as the PHP version is above 5.6:

```
$allowed_range = [ 'min' => 5, 'max' => 40 ];
$filtered = array_filter(
    $myArray,
    function ( $key ) use ( $allowed_ranged ) {
        return ( $key >= $allowed_range[ 'min' ] && $key <= $allowed_range[ 'max' ] );
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

Comment: I am the developer, not the system admin. When it's under my control, I exclusively use PHP 7 as an absolute minimum, but things aren't always that way unfortunately.

Comment: Upvoted for prosperity though. Anyone using outdated PHP should update immediately.

Comment: Understood - I put this here for future visitors as much as anything else, so not any sort of commentary on you or your skills!  I am a developer also, and know that we often have our hands tied...

Comment: Google App Engine is stuck on 5.5 so if you're running applications in Google's cloud then you're stuck with that version at least until google pull their finger out.

Comment: @GordonM - wow that's amazing that Google would have people locked down to old unsupported versions :\

Comment: @cale_b I guess they don't care about software they didn't write themselves. :P  But yeah, you'd think a big company that supposedly takes internet security so seriously would know better.