# Array Keys that contain a variable - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [message] => 
    [user_id] => 10
    [errors] => 
    [temp_access_token(emailabc@gmail.com)] => Array
        (
            [access_token] => 99abcdefghijk
            [generated] => 
        )

    [temp_access_token(emaildef@gmail.com)] => Array
        (
            [access_token] => 99klmopqrstuv
            [generated] =>
```

Here is how the array is being created:

```
$_SESSION["temp_access_token($username)"] = json_decode($access_token, true);
```

I am after the following values because I want to store them as $_SESSION variables.  The number of temp_access_token/email combinations is always unkown.

```
[temp_access_token(emailabc@gmail.com)][access_token];
[temp_access_token(emaildef@gmail.com)][access_token];
```

How do I step through this array, printing the access token for each email address?

Comment: Can you paste the whole code here ?

Comment: Like the array value

Comment: it helps to manipulate on my editor :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to use array\_filter() to filter array keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys)

Comment: The array value is posted above.  That's what I get when I print_r($array)....

Comment: This is a poorly-designed data structure. Why don't you have a single `temp_access_token` array, whose value is an associative array of `email => ['access_token' => xxx, 'generated' => yyy]`?

Comment: Ok.  How would I do that (still keeping them in SESSION variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the email addresses?

If so you can create a foreach loop, and access each of the arrays.

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $array['temp_access_token('.$email.)']['accesstoken'];
}
```

If not you can loop through the array, and do a substring of the key, something like this (psuedocode, might not all work in practice)

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
    if(strpos($key, 'temp_access_token') !== false) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: The value for the email address is held in the variable called $username

Comment: $array['temp_access_token('.$username.)']['accesstoken'];  You may need to play with the single quotes and doublequotes

Comment: Still not getting me there.  This is what I have now:       foreach($_SESSION as $username) {
      print $_SESSION['temp_access_token('.$username.')']['access_token']."<br />";
  }

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You will need to print_r $username.  I don't think that variable contains what you think it does.

Comment: I'm getting closer...this almost has me there.  Just need to tweak it a little.  Thank you for your help.   foreach ($_SESSION as $temptoken) {   
      print $_SESSION['temp_access_token('.($_SESSION['username']).')']['access_token'] . "<br />";
  }

Comment: Sorry, one more question.  If I want to loop through the array, using substring of the key, how would I print the key and matching value?                foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$val) {
       if(strpos($key, 'temp_access_token') !== false) {
         
         print $_SESSION['temp_access_token']['access_token']."<br />";
      }
}

Comment: You can print the key with $key, and the matching value using strpos function