# How to get a subset of an array's values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Given:

```
$info = ['abc'=>'xyz', '123'=>'456', 'vowels'=>'aeiou'];  //complete data array
$keys = ['abc','123'];  //list of keys I'm interested in getting the VALUES for
```

What's the best way to get an array like this (no KEYS in it):

```
['xyz','456']
```

Currently, I have this, but feel there might be some other way with PHP's built-in array functions:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $result[] = $info[$key];
}

return $result;
```

Other answers describe a 'pluck' type function, but those all return keys too... I only want the values.

**Update**: The answer seems to be a combination of two responses below:

```
array_values(array_intersect_key($info,array_flip($keys)));
```

Comment: `['abc','123']` != `['xyz','456']`, so which is it, do you want the keys or the values?

Comment: `array_values()` for values `array_keys()` for keys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just wanted the values; I didn't mention ['abc','123'] in "what the best way to get" part.  I will use array_values() like this, thank you

    array_values(array_intersect_key($info,array_flip($keys)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing particularly bad about your approach, but here are a couple of alternatives

```
$info = ['abc'=>'xyz', '123'=>'456', 'vowels'=>'aeiou'];  //complete data array
$keys = ['abc','123'];  //list of keys I'm interested in

$out=array_intersect_key($info,array_flip($keys));

print_r($out);
```

> Array (
>       [abc] => xyz
>       [123] => 456 )

OR

```
$out= array_map(function($x) use ($info) { return $info[$x]; }, $keys);

print_r($out);
```

> Array (
>       [0] => xyz
>       [1] => 456 )

Comment: Thank you. I will take the Array ( [abc] => xyz [123] => 456 ) output and apply array_values() to it!