# PHP get values by given keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
$user = [
'id' => 1,
'fname' => 'name1',
'lname' => 'lname',
'age' => 20
];
```

I want to get values by given keys. Is there function already.

```
$userData = array....($user, ['fname', 'lname']); // get only fname and lname from user
```

I dont want to to for loops or similar.

Thanks

Comment: does `array_filter` fine? with ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys

Comment: Without looping, it isn't possible. You may use functions but they do the same under the hood. Maybe you are looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: refrence here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_intersect_key`, after flipping the second array to an associative array.

```
$userData = array_intersect_key($user, array_flip(['fname', 'lname']));
```

Comment: Thanks, that was I was looking for, even though php creaters could create more descriptive function

Comment: I don't think this is a common operation. The function you want doesn't exist in JavaScript or Python, either.