# Get values of array using as key values of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some values (numeric values):

```
$arr1 = [1, 3, 8, 12, 23]
```

and I have another associative array that a key (which matches to a value of `$arr1`) correspond to a value. This array may contain also keys that don't match with `$arr1`.

```
$arr2 = [1 => "foo", 2 => "foo98", 3 => "foo20", 8 => "foo02", 12 => "foo39", 15 => "foo44", 23 => "foo91", 34 => "foo77"]
```

I want as return the values of `$arr2` specifying as key the values of `$arr1`:

```
["foo", "foo20", "foo02", "foo39", "foo91"]
```

If possible, all this, without loops, using just PHP array native functions (so in an elegant way), or at least with the minimum number of loops possible.

Comment: Whether you can see the 'loops' or not, they will be there. So this cannot be done without 'looping' somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimal loop is simple - 1. as:

```
foreach($arr1 as $k) {
    $res[] = $arr2[$k];
}
```

You can do that with `array_walk` but I think this simple way is more readable.

If you insist you can do with `array_filter` + `array_values` + `in_array` as:

```
$res = array_values(array_filter($arr2,
    function ($key) use ($arr1) { return in_array($key, $arr1);},
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
));
```

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys) for more about filtering keys

Comment: I agree with that sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

To do it purely with array functions, you could do it as...

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($arr2, array_flip($arr1) ));
```

So `array_flip()` turns the items you want form the array into the keys for `$arr1` and then uses `array_intersect_key()` to match the keys with the main array and this newly created array.

Gives...

```
Array
(
    [1] => foo
    [3] => foo20
    [8] => foo02
    [12] => foo39
    [23] => foo91
)
```

If you don't want the keys - add `array_values()` around the rest of the calls...

```
print_r(array_values(array_intersect_key($arr2, array_flip($arr1) )));
```

to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => foo20
    [2] => foo02
    [3] => foo39
    [4] => foo91
)
```

Although as pointed out - sometimes a simple `foreach()` is just as good and sometimes better.