# Can I get only the array that meets the criteria in the total array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

There is a full array and a specific array.

I want to get only parts that fit a particular in the entire array.

For example, I have two arrays.

```
$all_array = array('a'=>'1', 'b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3', 'd'=>'4', 'e'=>'5')

$find_array = array('b', 'd', 'e')
```

Then, I want to get `$result_array`

`array('b'=>'2', 'd'=>'4', 'e'=>'5');` or `array('2', '4', '5');`

Is there a way to get result?

Comment: Yes there's a way. Now show some effort in solving __your__ problem.

Comment: Did you at least tried the simple `foreach` solution?

Comment: Thank you all.
I can solve it by using foreach, array_key_exists, etc.
I wondered if there was another best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner `array_intersect_key($all_array, array_flip($find_array));`

Comment: Look the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260168/6487675 ...

Comment: Oh, pardon me. Next time I'll search entire stackoverflow in order not to make duplicate answer

Comment: Not meant to offence - this is the first answer when doing google search on filter array by key (and in my opinion is the best solution here). And I also think that this question title is to general for the question itself - this title suggest the answer will be array_filter which takes function as argument

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_walk`

```
$r=[];
array_walk($find_array, function($v,$k) use($all_array,&$r){$r[$v] = $all_array[$v];});
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ReIIJ)

Answer (score 0):

`foreach()` the `$find_array` and check in `$all_array`, if exist, store it in new array.

```
$all_array = array('a'=>'1', 'b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3', 'd'=>'4', 'e'=>'5');

$find_array = array('b', 'd', 'e');
$new = array();
foreach($find_array as $val){
    if(isset($all_array[$val])){
        $new[$val] = $all_array[$val];
    }
}
print_r($new);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jppbg)