# Filter array from big data collection of data

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays one is the collection of key and other with a collection of data ex.

```
$array1 = ['0'=>'A1','1'=>'A2','2'=>'A3'];
```

and

```
$array2 = ['A1'=>'Data1','A2'=>'Data2','A3'=>'Data3','A4'=>'Data4','A5'=>'Data5'];
```

I want data like this

```
$array = ['A1'=>'Data1','A2'=>'Data2','A3'=>'Data3']
```

Comment: Best option from duplicate (IMHO) is `$output = array_intersect_key($array2, array_flip($array1))`

Comment: I was just typing that answer. Agree with Nigel.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this:

```
$my_array = ['A1'=>'Data1','A2'=>'Data2','A3'=>'Data3','A4'=>'Data4','A5'=>'Data5'];
$allowed  = ['0'=>'A1','1'=>'A2','2'=>'A3']; 
$filtered = array_filter(
    $my_array,
    function ($key) use ($allowed) {
        return in_array($key, $allowed);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);

var_dump($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["A1"]=>
  string(5) "Data1"
  ["A2"]=>
  string(5) "Data2"
  ["A3"]=>
  string(5) "Data3"
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ZvkJb

Credit: [PHP: How to use array_filter() to filter array keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260086/php-how-to-use-array-filter-to-filter-array-keys)

Comment: You should update the code in your question to match your demo. As it is, what is in the question won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one to get the exact data of `$array2` as you mentioned in the question.

```
$array1 = ['0'=>'A1','1'=>'A2','2'=>'A3']; 
$array2 = ['A1'=>'Data1','A2'=>'Data2','A3'=>'Data3','A4'=>'Data4','A5'=>'Data5']; 
$ans = [];
foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    if(isset($array2[$value]))
        $ans[$value] = $array2[$value];
}
print_r($ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `$array1` a dic, then check if key in `$array2` is set in the dic.

```
$array1 = array_flip($array1);
$result = [];
foreach($array2 as $k => $v){
    if(isset($array1[$k])){
        $result[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```